# image resize in show method using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Iam using same code in my index and show page. but i can't able to resize in show method and my code is

```
<%= image_tag @language.image_url, size:"100*100" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an asterix in your `size` attribute. Did you try it with the `x` character between the width and height numbers?

```
<%= image_tag @language.image_url, size:"100x100" %>
```

As some of the other posters have mentioned here, if you're using paperclip, it might be a better idea to resize and store your resized image via paperclip for performance reasons. But if you want to keep the image resizing in HTML, then try using `x` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 2):

you can resize as follows:

```
<%= image_tag @language.image_url, width: 100, height: 100 %>
```

Comment: It's not the correct way to do, if you are using the paperclip gem theb create a image with required styles.

Comment: This way is not wrong per se. It just might not be the most efficient way to do image sizing, but it's technically wrong.

Comment: its not wrong any way check out this>>http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: Oops, I meant to say it's ***not*** technically wrong. @Mayanak, I completely agree with you. Your solution is correct. I was disputing Bharat soni's point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<%= image_tag(@language.image_url), :style=>'width:100px; height:100px;'%>
```

But you are using the paperclip gems and it provide styles to create the image with required resoluctions.

Below is the example of code that set can be set with paperclip.

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "117x245>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```